# Tensorflow Serving Client: Socket Closed Error

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, tensorflow-serving

I'm new to Tensorflow Serving. I'm following the tutorial describe here
https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/serving_inception#part_0_create_a_docker_image

I already setup the image and the cluster is running and everything. However when trying to run the client locally. I receive the next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "inception_client.py", line 56, in <module>
    tf.app.run()   File "/home/dangz90/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))   File "inception_client.py", line 51, in main
    result = stub.Predict(request, 30.0)  # 10 secs timeout   File "/home/dangz90/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grpc/beta/_client_adaptations.py", line 309, in __call__
    self._request_serializer, self._response_deserializer)   File "/home/dangz90/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grpc/beta/_client_adaptations.py", line 195, in _blocking_unary_unary
    raise _abortion_error(rpc_error_call) grpc.framework.interfaces.face.face.AbortionError: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE, details="Socket closed")
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you solve it? Can you share the solution? Thank you.

Comment: @DiegoOrellana Yes! I was able to solve it. I tried different things. 1) Add more time to timeout, some models take more time to load. 2) I run inception_client from inside the folder, it seems like there was a mistake in my installation (could be your case also) and it can only work by running the file from inside the same folder. 3) This was quite strange, I printed the configuration to see if there was a mistake and then it worked, later I just deleted the print, quite strange but it also worked. Do let me know if these workarounds worked for you.

Comment: @Daniel Zapata Can you show a example code to solve it ?